# I cannot compare three numbers rigthly in C

Tags: c

i have issue with comparing three numbers in C. I tried to type three numbers, find the largest and smallest but first else doesnt work in if statment rightly.

I cannot find out the largest and smallest number when i tried diffrent combination of numbers.

```
int main() {
    double a, b, c, max, min;
    printf("Type number a\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &a);
    printf("Type number b\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &b);
    printf("Type number c\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &c);
    printf("Yours numbers %lf/%lf/%lf\n", a, b, c);


    if (a > b) {
        max = a;
        min = b;
    }
    else (a < b); {
        max = b;
        min = a;
    }
    if (c > max) {
        max = c;

    }
    else (c < min); {
        min = c;
    }
    printf("Yours largest number is: %lf\n", max);
    printf("Yours smallest number is %lf\n", min);

    printf("Sum of yours numbers %lf\n", a + b + c);
}
```

Comment: You are missing the "equal" cases.

Comment: By the way.. `else (a < b)` is invalid syntax. Does it even compile?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well `(a < b);` is a valid statement, so why wouldn't it compile? clang does throw some warnings at you though, even by default. Not sure about gcc.

Comment: @Siguza You got me here. Missed the `;`.

Comment: If i dont use  (a < b); VS 2019 show problems expected a ';' and syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

Comment: Of course. Because you missed `if` as in in `else if (..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you write:

```
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
    min = b;
}
else (a < b); {
    max = b;
    min = a;
}
```

you really want to write:

```
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
    min = b;
}
else {
    max = b;
    min = a;
}
```

The compiler reads your code more like this

```
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
    min = b;
}
else 
    (a < b); 

{ max = b; min = a; }
```

Comment: I tried second solution but its same result. When I type 3,4,6, the largest is 6 also smallest 6.

Comment: Did you also fix the second if clause? In general when you put a statement like `(a < b);` or `printf("Hello");` or  a group of statements enclosed by braces`{}` the compiler will only consider the first "thing" as the else part and the next "thing" is always executed like regular code.

Comment: I fixed but next have another issue. I tried pair of numbers 213, -21.4, 0.451. My type variables are float/ Can float return negative number as the smallest?

Comment: I am not sure what's the issue exactly, but yes, floats can also take on negative values. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: When i`m comparing 213, -21.4, 0.451, the largest number is 213 but the smallest is 0.451 than -21.4 but as you know its not true.

Comment: @Laurent That's because the `else` there is wrong. After you have determined that min = -21.4 and max = 213, if your code  is like `if (c > max) { max = c;} else ...`, with c = 0.451, which is *not* greater than 213, you'll end up with `min = c;`. Which is wrong. Use `if (c > max) { } if (c < min) {}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the construct

```
if ( some_condition ) {
     // Do something 
}
else {  
     // I'm here because some_condition is false
}
```

with

```
if ( some_condition ) {
    // Do something
}
else if ( another_condition )
{
    // Here some_condition is false AND another_condition is true
}
else
{
    // Both are false
}
```

The `else` clause in the former doesn't expect a condition at all, if you put an expression like `(a < b);` after that, its result is ignored.

Consider the following alternative

```
double min = a;    // Make an assumption. It would be correct even if a == b,
double max = b;    // but not if...

if ( b < a )
{
    max = a;
    min = b;
}

if ( c < min )    // Note that using 'if (c < min) { min = c; } else { max = c; }' 
{                 // here, would be an error.
    min = c;      // Consider e.g. a = 2, b = 1, c = 1. After the previous statements   
}                 // We would have min = 1 and max = 2, so that, beeing c equal to min,
if ( c > max )    // the 'else' clause would be incorrectly chosen.
{
    max = c;
}
```

Comment: This method eliminate one if.